# How can I view only the first n lines of the file?

Tags: shell, csh

I tried head +10 and it didn't work.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Did you try the man page for head?

```
head -n 10 filename
```

Answer (score 13):

Head is a fine tool, but you might also try:

```
sed 10q path
```

For code golf fanatics, sed is always better than head :)

Comment: can you explain this line please?

Comment: sed reads a line, then prints it.  When it gets to line 10, it prints the line and then quits.