# How to display n number of lines of a file which is passed as a argument in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a log file and I want to print the first *n* lines from the log file by passing *n* as an argument in bash.
Example:

```
./hello.sh -n 10 filename
```

Output should be: First 10 lines of the file.

Comment: head -10 filename [should do it]

Comment: @WalterA it's `sed 10q filename`

Comment: `head` does what you ask for. If you give it no parameters, just `head filename`, it'll default to the first 10 lines; you can specify the number of lines using an `-n` parameter as in `head -n 15 filename`. For compatibility reasons, a deprecated syntax `head -15 filename` is also supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read first x lines of csv file into new outfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275072/read-first-x-lines-of-csv-file-into-new-outfile)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411070/how-can-i-view-only-the-first-n-lines-of-the-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view only the first n lines of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411070/how-can-i-view-only-the-first-n-lines-of-the-file)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `head` command on your terminal.

```
head -10 <filename>.log
```

This should do the job.